# Unable to get custom label from page conversations api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-ads-api

**Fetched the Page conversation**

```
GET /v18.0/<page_id>/conversations?fields=id,message_count,participants
```

We successfully got the participants along with the name and id (page scoped user id)

**Error while making api call to get custom label**

```
GET /v18.0/<user_psid>/custom_labels?fields=page_label_name&access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

{
"error": {
"message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID 'xxxxxx' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api%22),
"type": "GraphMethodException",
"code": 100,
"error_subcode": 33,
"fbtrace_id": "AacbMQx3cl5vIePPE6449iS"
}
}

We already have pages_messaging and pages_read_engagement permission approved. Does anyone know why we keep getting errors although all required permissions are approved?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this request:

```
GET /v19.0/<user_psid>/custom_labels?access_token=<PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

This endpoint doesn't have any parameters.

Source:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v19.0/user/custom_labels

Comment: Already tried that but no luck :(

Answer (score 0):

From the facebook graph api documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/custom-labels/#retrieving_labels_by_psid

> Currently, Messenger Platform do not support retrieving labels for
> Messenger accounts that were created using a phone number instead of a
> Facebook account.

This can be a possible culprit.